# Build a Binary on Multilevel Directory structure in yocto

Tags: yocto

Does yocto support multiple level directory structure for bin_PROGRAMS?

My dir looks something like this :

source

|_____subdir1/subdir1.1/subdir/1.2/.../subdir1.5

|____subdir2/subdir2.1/subdir/2.2/.../subdir2.5

Code is mix of C and CPP files.

I have introduced bin_PROGRAMS based Makefile.am in all the dirs to cover directory specific C or CPP files. Is this the right way to achieve single binary for a multilevel directory source code?

I get undefined reference to main function when subdir1 is compiled.
Actual main fn is available at subdir2.1 in above dir representation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.